# Google api And different flavors in my app

Tags: android, google-api, android-productflavors, google-play-console

I have three flavors in my app that are published as three different apps to the Play Store. So they have unique names and applicationIds.

I've registered my app (it's main flavor) at google play console to get Google Drive API key. It works fine, but only for the main flavour, because API key is bound to the app name.

GP Console won't let me create a new client Id, because my fingerprint (package + SHA1) are identical for all three flavors.

What can I do to obtain new client Ids for my other flavors?

Here's the error log if I try to run it with the same API key for extra flavors:

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution?

Comment: @Renjith Hi! Yes, every app(flavor) is signed by PlayConsole and you must use unique SHA1 issued for each app by google. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: I was using API for Google Maps. Recently I started using Geolocation API where I faced the issue of SHA1 fingerprint restriction is not applied and the API always returned access denied message

Comment: Initially thought it was an error with different flavours, but later came to know it isn't